# Extract attributes from xml in nifi

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, apache-nifi

I have these xml files where I get them from ftp (with list and fetch ftp processor). I want to get the values from the xml file and replace the file with these values as it was a csv . (and put them back to ftp with putFtp processor)

The desired output is something like this:

```
{"foodate":"somedate","name":"fooid1_foovalue","value":5.44}
{"foodate":"somedate","name":"fooid1_metrics","value":some-metrics}
.
.
.
{"foodate":"somedate","name":"fooid2_foovalue","value":2.34}
.
.
.
```

So for each id write first foodate attribute and then id1 , sample - attribute 1, id1,  sample - attribute 2, etc.

However each time I dont know the name or how many the attributes will be.Only that the first sample attribute will be foodate. Any idea how to procceed? I tried with executeScript processor and js but it seems to not recognize DOMParser() etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Document Version="2">
    <ExportData lowerBound="2021/11/24 16:58:26" upperBound="2021/11/24 22:58:26">
        <Site name="name" f="">
            <Kapta fooid1="some-number">
                <Infos>
                    <Info>
                        <EndPoint foo="value-name" />
                    </Info>
                </Infos>
                <Samples ordering="desc">
                    <Sample foodate="some-date" foovalue="5.44" metrics="some-metrics" metrics2="metrics-again" value="numbers5" te="numbers" />
                    <Sample foodate="some-date" foovalue="7.45" foom="some-metrics" metrics453="metrics-again" otherattribut="numbers5" att345="numbers" morevalues="numbers" foohdeiurf="numbers" hello="numbers"/>
                </Samples>
            </Kapta>
            <Kapta fooid2="some-number">
                <Infos>
                    <Info>
                        <EndPoint foo="value-name" />
                    </Info>
                </Infos>
                <Samples ordering="desc">
                    <Sample foodate="some-date" foovalue="2.34" metrics="some-metrics" metrics2="metrics-again" value="numbers" te="numbersagain" />
                    <Sample foodate="some-date" foo="99.8" metrics="some-metrics" metrics2="metrics-again" value="numbers" te="numbers" />
                    <Sample foodate="some-date" attr="234.56" someothermetrics="some-metrics" metr="metrics-again" anothervalue="numbers" />
                </Samples>
            </Kapta>
        </Site>
    </ExportData>
</Document>

Thanks a lot for your time and effort!
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is something like 
{fooid, foodate="some-date" foovalue="some-numbers" metrics="some-metrics" metrics2="metrics-again" value="numbers5" te="numbers"} 
{fooid, foodate="some-date" foovalue="some-numbers" foom="some-metrics" metrics453="metrics-again" otherattribut="numbers5" att345="numbers" morevalues="numbers" foohdeiurf="numbers" hello="numbers"}

Comment: And where you want to place it? Flow file content or attribute? Is it a json format? Please edit your question and provide answers including expected result.

Comment: You are right I will edit my question and add more details.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groovy xml parser libraries. There are lots of option according to your needs, check [this](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html)

Here is an experimental code, it gets the xml from content of incoming flow file and outputs some extractions as json list. You can develop it with your requirement

Please note that this code may not be production grade. See [ExecuteScript cookbook](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922) for more about Groovy in Nifi

```java
import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.InputStreamCallback
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator

def flowFile

try {
    
    flowFile = session.get()
    
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = null

    session.read(flowFile, {inputStream ->
        doc =  dBuilder.parse(inputStream)
    } as InputStreamCallback)
    
    def root = doc.documentElement
    def sb = new StringBuilder()
    def jsonGenerator = new JsonGenerator.Options().disableUnicodeEscaping().build()
    
    // get a specific attribute
    use(DOMCategory) {
         root['ExportData']['Site']['Kapta']['Infos']['Info']['*'].findAll { node ->
            def data = new LinkedHashMap()
            data.NodeName = node.name()
            data.foodate = node['@foo']
            sb.append(jsonGenerator.toJson(data))
            sb.append('\n')
        }   
    }
    
    // get all attributes of Sample under Samples
    use(DOMCategory) {
        root['ExportData']['Site']['Kapta']['Samples']['*'].findAll { node ->
            def data = new LinkedHashMap()
            data.NodeName = node.name()
            def attributesMap = node.attributes()
            for (int x = 0; x < attributesMap.getLength(); x++) {
                data.AttrName = attributesMap.item(x).getNodeName();
                data.AttrValue = attributesMap.item(x).getNodeValue();
                sb.append(jsonGenerator.toJson(data))
                sb.append('\n')
            }
                    
       }
    }   
    
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
        outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    } as StreamCallback)
    
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error('',e)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Actually I get the files through ftp and put them back in. Im not sure hot to see the logs as your script shows the values there. It was my fault cause I didnt describe the desired output. I want to replace the xml file that I got from ftp with the values from xml . For each fooid I want to write a line with the id and the sample values . For example  {fooid1, sample1 - attributes} {fooid1, sample2 - attributes } {fooid2,sample1 - attributes } etc

Comment: Logs can be seen in nifi-app.log file under /log folder. Anyway, I edited my answer concerning your update. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you!I will try to develop the existing code more to fit my needs, but it was a great help to start!

Comment: thank you for your time answering my question. Based on the above code how can I print all atributes names and values in my file?

Comment: I suppose you don't know attributes beforehand and want to get them dynamically . I edited my answer.

Comment: Yes exactly! Thanks! I'm starting to understand better now! But one more question. How can I have this output?
- line1: foodate:value, fooid(that is attribute from kapta tag), dynamic attribute name from <sample>: value of this attribute
- line2: foodate:value, fooid(that is attribute from kapta tag), next dynamic attribute name from <sample>: value of this attribute

Comment: To analyze it further I want to print for each fooid its sample attributes