# Groovy script (NiFi) - xml select dynamically attributes of child node

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, apache-nifi

I have an xml structure like this:

```
    <Site >
        <Za id1="id1">
            <Infos>
                <Info>
                    <EndPoint foo="value-name" />
                </Info>
            </Infos>
            <Samples>
                <Sample date="date" attribute1="5.44" attribute2="234" attribute3="8.45"/>
                <Sample date="date" attribute1="7.45" attribute5="8.45"/>
            </Samples>
        </Za>
        <Za id2="id2">
            <Infos>
                <Info>
                    <EndPoint foo="value-name" />
                </Info>
            </Infos>
            <Samples>
                <Sample date="date" attribute1="5.44" attribute2="234" attribute3="8.45"/>
                <Sample date="date" attribute1="7.45" attribute5="8.45" attribute6="7.45" attribute7="8.45"/>
            </Samples>
        </Za>
    </Site>
```

The desired output is like this:

```
 {"time":"date1","name":"id1_attribute1","value":5.44}
 {"time":"date1","name":"id1_attribute2","value":234}
 {"time":"date1","name":"id1_attribute3","value":8.45}
 {"time":"date2","name":"id1_attribute4","value":7.45}
 {"time":"date2","name":"id1_attribute5","value":8.45}
 {"time":"date3","name":"id2_attribute1","value":5.44}
 .
 .
 .
```

I get the files through (list and fetch ftp processor in NiFi but I'm not able to print my desired output.

I am trying to get my desired output through this code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70366709/extract-attributes-from-xml-in-nifi) related question but Im not sure how to change it in order to get it right.

So the code is this one bellow:

```
import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.InputStreamCallback
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.StreamCallback
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import groovy.xml.dom.DOMCategory
import groovy.json.JsonGenerator

def flowFile

try {

  flowFile = session.get()

  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = null

session.read(flowFile, {inputStream ->
    doc =  dBuilder.parse(inputStream)
} as InputStreamCallback)

def root = doc.documentElement
def sb = new StringBuilder()
def jsonGenerator = new 
 JsonGenerator.Options().disableUnicodeEscaping().build()

// get a specific attribute
use(DOMCategory) {
    root['ExportData']['Site']['*'].findAll { node ->
        def data = new LinkedHashMap()
        data.id = node['@id1']
        sb.append(jsonGenerator.toJson(data))
        sb.append('\n')
    }   
 }

  // get all attributes of Sample under Samples
  use(DOMCategory) {
    root['ExportData']['Site']['Kapta']['Samples']['*'].findAll { 
  node ->
        def data = new LinkedHashMap()
        data.NodeName = node.name()
        def attributesMap = node.attributes()
        for (int x = 0; x < attributesMap.getLength(); x++) {
            data.AttrName = attributesMap.item(x).getNodeName();
            data.AttrValue = attributesMap.item(x).getNodeValue();
            sb.append(jsonGenerator.toJson(data))
            sb.append('\n')
        }
                
   }
 }   

 flowFile = session.write(flowFile, {inputStream, outputStream ->
    
 outputStream.write(sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
 } as StreamCallback)

 session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)

 } catch (Exception e) {
   log.error('',e)
   session.transfer(flowFile, REL_FAILURE)
 }
```

This code outputs a attribute id and then dynamically all sample attributes. I want to print as I have described above for each id, its sample attributes.

Thanks a lot for your time and effort!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it. "but I'm not able to print my desired output" - what is the problem? does it not print at all? does it print the wrong thing? why is it wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your notes, I edited my question,please check again!

Comment: Could you please add the output you get and point why it is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code for `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor

```js
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def ff = session.get()
if(!ff) return

ff.write{streamIn, streamOut->
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(streamIn)
    def json = xml.ExportData.Site.Kapta.Samples.Sample.collectMany{sample->
        def attr = sample.attributes()
        def date = attr.remove('date')
        //use regexp to find id attribute by prefix `id`
        def id = sample.parent().parent().attributes().find{ k,v-> k =~ "^id.*" }.value
        attr.collect{k,v->
            [
                time: date,
                name: "${id}_${k}",
                value: new BigDecimal(v),
            ]
        }
    }
    streamOut.withWriter("UTF-8"){w-> new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(w) }
}
ff."mime.type" = "application/json"
REL_SUCCESS<<ff
```

output:

```
[
    {
        "time": "date1",
        "name": "id1_attribute1",
        "value": 5.44
    },
    {
        "time": "date1",
        "name": "id1_attribute2",
        "value": 234
    },
    {
        "time": "date1",
        "name": "id1_attribute3",
        "value": 8.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date2",
        "name": "id1_attribute1",
        "value": 7.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date2",
        "name": "id1_attribute5",
        "value": 8.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date3",
        "name": "id2_attribute1",
        "value": 5.44
    },
    {
        "time": "date3",
        "name": "id2_attribute2",
        "value": 234
    },
    {
        "time": "date3",
        "name": "id2_attribute3",
        "value": 8.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date4",
        "name": "id2_attribute1",
        "value": 7.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date4",
        "name": "id2_attribute5",
        "value": 8.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date4",
        "name": "id2_attribute6",
        "value": 7.45
    },
    {
        "time": "date4",
        "name": "id2_attribute7",
        "value": 8.45
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried the script and I am getting this error

Comment: ExecuteScript[id=be8ea6ad-017d-1000-f152-21ac2f1f011e] Failed to process session due to javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.nifi.controller.repository.StandardFlowFileRecord.write() is applicable for argument types: (Script5795$_run_closure1) values:

Comment: [Script5795$_run_closure1@1bca0a07] Possible solutions: wait(), wait(long), with(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(long, int), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter) ↳ causes

Comment: You have to use executeGroovyScript processor

Comment: Thank you it worked as expected!